# Electron project : open index.html or npm start, what changes?

Tags: javascript, electron

When I run npm start, it opens a GUI electron and it works fine.

On the other hand, When I open index.html, it opens chrome and it seems that not all sources are loaded.

What is the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

Electron provides a host of APIs and a Node.js backend that you don't get if you open an HTML document in a regular browser.